# Picking consecutive elements from row and then their selected element

Tags: matlab

I have a row vector like this:

```
x18 = [8193 8877 8881 8885 9589 10610 10611 10775 10777 11512 11516];
```

I want that whenever consecutive numbers(with difference less than or equal to 4) appear, they must be separated in new row vector and then 2nd elements.
I want output as:

```
y = [8877 8881 8885 10610 10611 10775 10777 11512 11516];
```

and finally:

```
z = [8881 10611 10777 11516];
```

skipping 8193 and 9589.
This is what I tried, but not getting satisfactory result.

```
x18= [8193 8877 8881 8885 9589 10610 10611 10775 10777 11512 11516];
for i=1:length(x18)-1
    y1(:,i)=x18(i+1)-x18(i) ;

end
y2=find(y1<=4);
y3=x18(y2);

for i=1:length(y3)-1
    y4(:,i)=y3(i+1)-y3(i) ;

end
y5= find(y4>100);
x6=[2 y5+2];
x6(x6>length(y3))=[];
x14=y3(x6)
z=x14;

% My z=[ 8881 10775 11512]
% whereas I want : 
% z=[8881 10611 10777 11516]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part:

```
aux = find(abs(diff(x18))<=4);
ind = union(aux,aux+1);
y = x18(ind);
```

For the second part, I think this does what you want:

```
aux2 = abs(diff(y))<=4;
ind2 = find(diff([0 aux2])==1)+1;
z = y(ind2);
```

Comment: Thanks. In second part I want that from each of these consecutive numbers in y, pick second element e.g pick 8881 out of [8877 8881 8885],10611 out of [10610 10611] ,10777 out of [10775 10777]and 11516 out of [11512 11516].

Comment: Thanks brother. How can I get the remaining two elements 8193 and 9589.

Comment: @MuhammadAkmal `x18(setdiff(1:numel(y),ind))`